# Leader election in Mesos cluster seems not working

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper, mesos, mesosphere

I am setting up Mesos Cluster(ZooKeeper+Mesos) using docker, with 3 nodes(A,B,C) running zookeeper&master&slave containers for each.

**node B & C redirects each other (quorum=2)**

As I run Mesos-Master container and open Mesos Web UI,

- node A seems like a master node
- node B redirects to node C
- node C redirects to node B

It seems strange that node A is isolated and node B and C redirects each other forever.

**What is happening here?**

`docker run` command for Mesos-Master is as following.
(Same for 3 nodes except `MESOS_IP`)

```
docker run 
--net=host 
-e MESOS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mesos 
-e MESOS_ZK=zk://<hostname-nodeA>:2181,<hostname-nodeB>:2181,<hostname-nodeC>:2181/mesos 
-e MESOS_CLUSTER=cheeter 
-e MESOS_HOSTNAME=<hostname-nodeA> 
-e MESOS_WORK_DIR=/var/lib/mesos 
-e MESOS_QUORUM=2 
-e MESOS_ISOLATOR=cgroups/cpu,cgroups/mem,cgroups/devices 
-e MESOS_CONTAINERIZERS=docker,mesos 
-e MESOS_IP=<ip-nodeA> 
-p 5050:5050 
-v /run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
-v /var/log:/var/log 
-v /cgroup:/cgroup 
-v /sys:/sys 
-v /proc:/proc 
-t mesosphere/mesos-master:0.20.1
```

`docker run` command for ZooKeeper is as following.
(Same for 3 nodes except `ZOOKEEPER_ID`)

```
docker run 
-e ZOOKEEPER_ID=1 
-e ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_1=<hostname-nodeA>:2888:3888 
-e ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_2=<hostname-nodeB>:2888:3888 
-e ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_3=<hostname-nodeC>:2888:3888 
-e ZOOKEEPER_DATADIR=/var/zookeeper 
-p 2181:2181 
-p 2888:2888 
-p 3888:3888 
-v /var:/var 
-v /sys:/sys 
-v /proc:/proc 
-v /cgroup:/cgroup 
-t jplock/zookeeper:3.4.6
```

I have tried to change quorum number 1-3, and the results were;

**3 nodes redirects in roop (quorum=1)**

As I run Mesos-Master with `quorum=1`, nodes redirects in roop like A->B->C->A->....

**Each node shows "No master is currently leading..." (quorum=3)**

As I run Mesos-Master with `quorum=1`, no redirection happened and each node shows "No master is currently leading..."

Answer (score 0):

For 3 master nodes quorum should be at least 2 (see http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/). Could you please share master logs? They may help to understand what went wrong.

Comment: According to '''docker run 
..
-e MESOS_QUORUM=2''' quorum size should be 2